# jquery text box keypress event

Tags: jquery

What I really want to do is run a function on every input box in a table.  The table has a class BudgetTable so I though

```
$(".BudgetTable tr input:text").keypress...
```

would work but in VS2010 the breakpoint was not hitting.

So I create a simple page to make sure it wasn't the mark up and so I can post something here that isn't too complex.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Budget.aspx.cs" Inherits="BudgetApplicationWeb.Budget" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dth XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/Dth/xhtml1-transitional.dth">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/BudgetGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    window.my_config = 
    { 
        last_section : "",
        current_section_row:0
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tr").each(function (index, domElem) {
            var className = $(this).attr("class");
            if (className == window.my_config.last_section) {

                window.my_config.current_section_row++;

                if (window.my_config.current_section_row % 2 == 0) {
                    $(this).addClass("alt");
                }

            }
            else if (className != "") {
                window.my_config.last_section = className;
                window.my_config.current_section_row = 0;
                if (window.my_config.last_section.toString().substr(0, 6) == "DataTR") {
                    $(this).addClass("alt");
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $("input").keypress(function (event) {
        var className = $(this).attr("class");
        var str = "";

        str += "ClassName:" + className + "<BR>"
        str += "ParentItem:" + className.toString().replace("Item", "") + "<BR>"

        // $("#debug").text = str;
        $("#debug").text = "hello";
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">   
    <div id="debug">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked at the post

[How do I Select all text boxes in a table excluding the last one in the table row with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638206/how-do-i-select-all-text-boxes-in-a-table-excluding-the-last-one-in-the-table-row)

I can not figure out why keypress is not working.

Thanks for the help

Comment: try adding a colon in front of input so you have $(":input").keypress..

Comment: did not seem to do anything.  I thought : was for types or filters like odd even not elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of red flags

1. You're not binding this in the document.ready
2. The textbox doesn't have a class so your className line won't work
3. className.toString() is redundant

Also, are you using firebug and are you seeing any console error messages?

Comment: 2 I am not worried about because the real page will have a class, 3 the toString I used to get to the replace function (at least in intellisense and for 1, well I don't see any bind in this example.  http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: In that example the jQuery came after the DOM elements. If you include it before (and without document.ready) it will execute immediately. There will be no DOM elements for it to bind to.

Comment: No errors in firebug but when I type $("input").keypress I get "function()" empty function

Comment: @Mike Robinson is correct the $("input").keypress needs to be inside the document.ready. I missed that first time. see http://jsfiddle.net/bUQ3f/

Comment: That makes sense, since referencing just the function name "keypress" instead of executing it "keyPress()" will return a reference to the function.

Comment: The binding work.  Now for best practice is it better to bind or have the script at the end of the pages?

Comment: Always put your jQuery binding inside a document.ready. The only exception I know of is when working with jQuery Mobile, where you use $("#pagename").live("pagecreate", function(){})